# Best function for pulling multiple NetCDF files from server, indexing, looping, and saving on file?

Tags: python, urllib, netcdf

Pretty new to programming. I am trying to alter a script that was meant to pull .txt files containing data to now pull NetCDF files from an HTTP server, download, rename, and save locally (well another server location). I've pasted the base code including actual buoy data file names for NetCDF files. I believe there is an issue at the urlrequest line. I've tried `urllib.request.open` and `url.request.retrieve` and both give errors.

```
    import os
    import urllib
    import urllib.request
    import shutil
    import netCDF4
    import requests
           
    # Weblink for location of spectra and wave data
    webSpectra = 'https://dods.ndbc.noaa.gov/thredds/fileServer/data/swden/41004/41004w9999.nc'
    
    webWave = 'https://dods.ndbc.noaa.gov/thredds/fileServer/data/stdmet/41004/41004h9999.nc'
       
    #set save location for each
    saveloc = 'saveSpectra41004w9999.nc'
    saveloc2 = 'saveWave41004h9999.nc'
    
    # perform pull
    try:
            urllib.request.urlopen(webSpectra, saveloc)
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as exception:
            print('Station: 41004 spectra file not available')
            print(exception)
        
        try:     
            urllib.request.urlopen(webWave, saveloc2)    
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as exception:
            print('Station: 41004 wave file not available')
            print(exception)
        print ('Pulling data for 41004)
        print('Percent complete '+ str(round(100*(count/len(stationIndex)))))

    print('Done')
```

My errors

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-5e5ebd26fe46> in <module>
     59     # perform pull
     60     try:
---> 61         urllib.request.urlopen(webSpectra, saveloc)
     62     except urllib.error.HTTPError as exception:
     63         print('Station: 41004 spectra file not available')

/work/anaconda3/envs/aoes/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    221     else:
    222         opener = _opener
--> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    224 
    225 def install_opener(opener):

/work/anaconda3/envs/aoes/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    522         for processor in self.process_request.get(protocol, []):
    523             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 524             req = meth(req)
    525 
    526         response = self._open(req, data)

/work/anaconda3/envs/aoes/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in do_request_(self, request)
   1277                 msg = "POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, " \
   1278                       "or a file object. It cannot be of type str."
-> 1279                 raise TypeError(msg)
   1280             if not request.has_header('Content-type'):
   1281                 request.add_unredirected_header(

TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please ensure code is formatted correctly and is also reproducible. You have a URL, but do not provide the code that would tell someone the cause

Comment: Sorry, I will post the code. And sorry for the wrong tag use, new to stack! Will fix now.

Comment: Also, instead of using a typed list in the code, is there way to reference a .txt file that has those same station ids listed vertically? This is only a snippet of the stations, there are actually 1,300+ stations I need to loop through and look for NetCDF files.

Comment: Please revise this to a minimum reproducible example. Only 1 of your lines seems to be causing the problem, the loop appears irrelevant

Comment: I've shrunk it down to relevant lines and added in my errors. Added in a specific NetCDF file I know exists instead of looping to get filename.

Comment: You seem to be trying to download files from a server that does not exist. Can you provide a more general link to it, which should be able for opendap

Comment: Here's the location of the 'swden' NetCDF file access website, similar one exists for 'stdmet': https://dods.ndbc.noaa.gov/thredds/catalog/data/swden/41004/catalog.html?dataset=data/swden/41004/41004w9999.nc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to download the files by the looks of it. You can do this using nctoolkit (https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). This will download the files to a temporary location. You can then export to xarray or pandas etc., or just save the file.

Code below will work for one file:

```
import nctoolkit as nc
ds = nc.open_url('https://dods.ndbc.noaa.gov/thredds/fileServer/data/stdmet/41004/41004h9999.nc')
# convert to xarray dataset
ds_xr = ds.to_xarray()
# convert to pandas dataframe
df = ds.to_dataframe()
# save to location
ds.to_nc("outfile.nc")
```

If the above does not work due to dependency issues etc., you can just use urllib:

```
import urllib.request
url = 'https://dods.ndbc.noaa.gov/thredds/fileServer/data/stdmet/41004/41004h9999.nc'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, '/tmp/temp/nc')
```

Comment: This might be what I'm looking for! I'm having issues installing and adding nctoolkit to my packages and environment but once that is done I will test run it and let you know.

Comment: Hello, I have tried this method after finally getting nctoolkit installed and I now get the following error, "ValueError: cdo -L -z zip_9 copy /tmp/nctoolkitfdxqzyfjnctoolkittmp71zib7wy.nc /work/Observation-Data/NDBC/spectra/saveSpectra41004w9999.nc was not successful. Check output". Any ideas? I read nctoolkit has an issue with Windows but I'm running my environment on linux and scripting through jupyter notebook.

Comment: do you have write access to /work/Observation-Data/NDBC/spectra/?

Comment: Yes, I do. I've tried the alternative 'ds=nc.open_thredds' function since these files are on a THREDDS server but got a different error: "ValueError: did not find a match in any of xarray's currently installed IO backends ['netcdf4', 'scipy', 'cfgrib']. Consider explicitly selecting one of the installed backends via the ``engine`` parameter to xarray.open_dataset(), or installing additional IO dependencies"

Comment: strange. I've tried the code given on my Fedora box and it's fine. Maybe try setting zip=False in `to_nc`. There is possibly something weird going on with CDO in the background. I will check the code for to_nc to see if the error messages can be improved

Comment: I've modified my answer to give an additional bare bones option

Comment: Yes, I actually just figured that out 5 minutes ago. Scrapped the nctoolkit way in favor of using urllib.request.urlopen very similar to what you pasted above. Thank you for all of the help though! I will mark as solved.

Answer (score 0):

> ...and save locally.

From my understanding, you should `open()` a local file, rather than POSTing to a URL.

Comment: I'm actually just trying to copy and save it to a different private directory on another server. I clarified that a bit in the description.